# Create a Series from a Pandas DataFrame by choosing an element from different columns on each row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series, dataframe

My goal is to create a Series from a Pandas DataFrame by choosing an element from different columns on each row.

For example, I have the following DataFrame:

```
In [171]: pred[:10]
Out[171]: 
                     0  1  2
Timestamp                   
2010-12-21 00:00:00  0  0  1
2010-12-20 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-17 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-16 00:00:00  0  0  1
2010-12-15 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-14 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-13 00:00:00  0  0  1
2010-12-10 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-09 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-08 00:00:00  0  0  1
```

And, I have the following series:

```
In [172]: useProb[:10]
Out[172]: 
Timestamp
2010-12-21 00:00:00    1
2010-12-20 00:00:00    2
2010-12-17 00:00:00    1
2010-12-16 00:00:00    2
2010-12-15 00:00:00    2
2010-12-14 00:00:00    2
2010-12-13 00:00:00    0
2010-12-10 00:00:00    2
2010-12-09 00:00:00    2
2010-12-08 00:00:00    0
```

I would like to create a new series, usePred, that takes the values from pred, based on the column information in useProb to return the following:

```
In [172]: usePred[:10]
Out[172]: 
Timestamp
2010-12-21 00:00:00    0
2010-12-20 00:00:00    1
2010-12-17 00:00:00    1
2010-12-16 00:00:00    1
2010-12-15 00:00:00    1
2010-12-14 00:00:00    1
2010-12-13 00:00:00    0
2010-12-10 00:00:00    1
2010-12-09 00:00:00    1
2010-12-08 00:00:00    0
```

This last step is where I fail.  I've tried things like:

```
usePred = pd.DataFrame(index = pred.index)
for row in usePred:
    usePred['PREDS'].ix[row] = pred.ix[row, useProb[row]]
```

And, I've tried:

```
usePred['PREDS'] = pred.iloc[:,useProb]
```

I google'd and search on stackoverflow, for hours, but can't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to use [get dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.reshape.get_dummies.html) (which *should* be more efficient that apply):

```
In [11]: (pd.get_dummies(useProb) * pred).sum(axis=1)
Out[11]:
Timestamp
2010-12-21 00:00:00    0
2010-12-20 00:00:00    1
2010-12-17 00:00:00    1
2010-12-16 00:00:00    1
2010-12-15 00:00:00    1
2010-12-14 00:00:00    1
2010-12-13 00:00:00    0
2010-12-10 00:00:00    1
2010-12-09 00:00:00    1
2010-12-08 00:00:00    0
dtype: float64
```

You could use an apply with a couple of locs:

```
In [21]: pred.apply(lambda row: row.loc[useProb.loc[row.name]], axis=1)
Out[21]:
Timestamp
2010-12-21 00:00:00    0
2010-12-20 00:00:00    1
2010-12-17 00:00:00    1
2010-12-16 00:00:00    1
2010-12-15 00:00:00    1
2010-12-14 00:00:00    1
2010-12-13 00:00:00    0
2010-12-10 00:00:00    1
2010-12-09 00:00:00    1
2010-12-08 00:00:00    0
dtype: int64
```

*The trick being that you have access to the rows index via the name property.*

Comment: @Brian added another solution which is a little neater.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it using [DataFrame.lookup](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
pred.lookup(row_labels=pred.index, 
            col_labels=pred.columns[useProb['0']])
```

It seems to be exactly what you need, except that care must be taken to supply values which are *labels*. For example, if `pred.columns` are strings, and `useProb['0']` values are integers, then we could use

```
pred.columns[useProb['0']]
```

so that the values passed to the `col_labels` parameter are proper label values.

---

For example,

```
import io
import pandas as pd
content = io.BytesIO('''\
Timestamp  0  1  2
2010-12-21 00:00:00  0  0  1
2010-12-20 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-17 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-16 00:00:00  0  0  1
2010-12-15 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-14 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-13 00:00:00  0  0  1
2010-12-10 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-09 00:00:00  1  1  1
2010-12-08 00:00:00  0  0  1''')
pred = pd.read_table(content, sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])

content = io.BytesIO('''\
Timestamp  0
2010-12-21 00:00:00    1
2010-12-20 00:00:00    2
2010-12-17 00:00:00    1
2010-12-16 00:00:00    2
2010-12-15 00:00:00    2
2010-12-14 00:00:00    2
2010-12-13 00:00:00    0
2010-12-10 00:00:00    2
2010-12-09 00:00:00    2
2010-12-08 00:00:00    0''')
useProb = pd.read_table(content, sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])
print(pd.Series(pred.lookup(row_labels=pred.index, 
                col_labels=pred.columns[useProb['0']]),
                index=pred.index))
```

yields

```
    Timestamp
2010-12-21    0
2010-12-20    1
2010-12-17    1
2010-12-16    1
2010-12-15    1
2010-12-14    1
2010-12-13    0
2010-12-10    1
2010-12-09    1
2010-12-08    0
dtype: int64
```